# Geometric series: please explain the process for the formula

Tags: geometric-series

I get how the formula is made.  What I don't get is why *whoever* decided to multiply the equation by $(1-r)$.  I'm referencing this [link at Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression).  I get the mechanics, just not some of the logic.

Consider
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a^i=a^0+a^1+a^2+...+a^{n-2}+a^{n-1}
$$

I get that the ratio is $r$, but why multiply this equation by $(1-r)$ and not some other quantity minus $r$?

Thanks \
AndyAndy

Answer (score 1):

Actually the author is skipping a step. First you multiply the series by $r$ and then you subtract this from the original series to get that:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} ar^{k-1} - r\sum_{k=1}^{n} ar^{k-1} = (1-r)\sum_{k=1}^{n} ar^{k-1}$$

But expanding the left hand side we can see that lots of cancelation occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it goes the other way and comes from a high school formula:
\begin{align*}
1-a^2 &=(1-a)(1+a),\\
1-a^3 &=(1-a)(1+a+a^2),\\
\vdots\\
1-a^n &=(1-a)(1+a+a^2+\dots+a^{n-1}).
\end{align*}

Comment: Very interesting.  I had not seen this.  Thank you for pointing this out.